# Как вывести сообщение из properties во время валидации?

Tags: java, spring, валидация

Два поля с валидацией

```
    @NotEmpty(message = "validation.firstname.NotEmpty.message")
    @Size(min = 3, max = 60, message = "validation.firstname.Size.message")
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty(message = "validation.lastname.NotEmpty.message")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 40, message = "validation.lastname.Size.message")
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
```

messages.properties file:

```
alidation.firstname.NotEmpty.message=Имя не может быть пустым
validation.firstname.Size.message=Длинна имени от 3 до 60 символов
validation.lastname.NotEmpty.message=Фамилия не может быть пустая
validation.lastname.Size.message=Длинна фамилии от 2 до 40 символов
```

И бины, но два последних как я понял ни на что не влияют, буду рад если объясните для чего они нужны т.к. работает без них

```
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/il8n/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
        return messageSource;
    }
 @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setProviderClass(HibernateValidator.class);
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return validator;
    }
    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        MethodValidationPostProcessor mvProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        mvProcessor.setValidator(validator());
        return mvProcessor;
    }
```

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Собственно вопрос: как вместо validation.firstname.NotEmpty.message вывести информативное сообщение из проперти файла?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `message = "validation.firstname.NotEmpty.message"` на `message = "{validation.firstname.NotEmpty.message}"`

Comment: @Chubatiy пробовал, всё четно. Выводится то же самое, но в скобках

Comment: @Andrey у Вас точно нет опечатки в messages.properties -> `alidation` ?

Comment: @Chubatiy точно нет, просто когда задание писал ошибся

Comment: Приведите тогда пож. структуру проекта, класс с валидацией(где вызывается) и конфигурацию `spring`. У вас приложение `spring-boot`?